# User input makes length of list, but the list is missing numbers after removing duplicates

Tags: c#, random, duplicates

I have made a code which takes a user input and makes it the length of an `List<Numbers>`.

Then I have made a for loop where the user input is inserted as for how many times the loop should repeat..

But when I get the output it will miss x amount of numbers in the list, because of the remove duplicates function.

So if the user makes an input of 5, the list should contain 5 numbers, which are chosen from a `random.Next` function.
But sometimes it returns less numbers than what the user is asking for.

How do I get the full length of the list even after the removal of duplicates?

```
            int Gruppe1;
            int Gruppe2;
            int Gruppe3;
            Gruppe1 = Convert.ToInt32(Value1);
            Gruppe2 = Convert.ToInt32(Value2);
            Gruppe3 = Convert.ToInt32(Value3);
            List<int> Lottotal1 = new List<int>();
            List<int> Lottotal2 = new List<int>();
            List<int> Lottotal3 = new List<int>();

            // for(loop) som generer tallene i gruppe1
            for (int i = 0; i < Gruppe1; i++)
            {
                List<int> Unique1 = new List<int>(Lottotal1.Count);
                Lottotal1.Add(random.Next(1, 13));
                Unique1 = Lottotal1.Distinct().ToList();
                Unique1.Sort();

                for (int j = 0; j < Unique1.Count; j++)
                {
                    labelArray1[j].Text = Unique1[j].ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and translate the in-code comment in English?

Comment: Hi sorry for my late replay. But yeah I thought about it when I posted the text. But I will put the text in code in English or translate it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps storing the random value in a variable, and then adding to the list if it doesn't already exist would solve your issue here.

For example, your code here:

```
Lottotal1.Add(random.Next(1, 13));
```

Could be turned into:

```
var currentEntry = random.Next(1, 13);
if(!Lottotal1.Contains(currentEntry))
    Lottotal1.Add(currentEntry);
```

If you did that, you might be able to remove the `Unique` list you make as well, since you are checking if the value exists before you insert it, so the distinct check wouldn't be necessary.

You might be able to turn:

```
List<int> Unique1 = new List<int>(Lottotal1.Count);
Lottotal1.Add(random.Next(1, 13));
Unique1 = Lottotal1.Distinct().ToList();
Unique1.Sort();

for (int j = 0; j < Unique1.Count; j++)
{
    labelArray1[j].Text = Unique1[j].ToString();
                    

}
```

into:

```
var currentEntry = random.Next(1, 13);
if(!Lottotal1.Contains(currentEntry))
{
    Lottotal1.Add(currentEntry);
    Lottotal1.Sort();
}

for (int j = 0; j < Lottotal1.Count; j++)
{
    labelArray1[j].Text = Lottotal1[j].ToString();
}
```

If you did that, you could then also have it decrement the index of the outer loop if the value is not added (because it was a duplicate). That way the loop would go for another round.

That would look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Gruppe1; i++)
{
    var currentEntry = random.Next(1, 13);

    // if our list doesn't already contain the currentEntry, add it
    if(!Lottotal1.Contains(currentEntry))
    {
        Lottotal1.Add(currentEntry);
        Lottotal1.Sort();
    }
    else
    {
        // here we can decrement i, from the for loop
        i--;
    }
    
    
    for (int j = 0; j < Lottotal1.Count; j++)
    {
        labelArray1[j].Text = Lottotal1[j].ToString();
    }
}
```

That being said, it may be easier to understand a different approach using a `while` loop, which would look something like:

```
// while our list count is less than the user defined size
while(Lottotal.Count < Gruppe1)
{
   // generate a number
   var currentEntry = random.Next(1, 13);

   // if its not already in our list, add it
   if (!Lottotal1.Contains(currentEntry))
   {
       Lottotal1.Add(currentEntry);
   }
}


Lottotal1.Sort();
for (int j = 0; j < Lottotal1.Count; j++)
{
    labelArray1[j].Text = Lottotal1[j].ToString();
}
```